# Idiom expressing quickly realizing there's nothing much to learn

Tags: idiom-requests

In essence, I'm looking for an equivalent of the European *"hitting the ceiling"*. The context of usage will be similar to *"I decided to be a cook aid, but I quickly started hitting the ceiling prompting my decision to become a cook"*.

I tried my "google-fu" but the only references I was able to find were to a definition of "hitting the ceiling" as "being angry".

Comment: I'm not sure "hitting the ceiling" is exclusively European. I've heard it elsewhere as well.

Comment: You mean to say that there isn't much ***more*** to learn, not that "there's nothing much to learn."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the cook aide **outgrew their job** almost immediately, i.e., hit a *learning/personal development ceiling*. So, I would suggest as an answer the idiom **to outgrow one's job**, and obvious variants required by the context.

If you Google **outgrow a job**, you'll get tons of hits -- and advice on how to tell you've **outgrown your job** and what to do about it.